# Date-value is two days behind inserted value after sending via REST and saving with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, angular, date

I have a Angular Frontend with Java Backend and I'd like to use PrimeNG's DateInput to receive and save a Date. I got the following code for that:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="enddate" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" class="medium-field"></p-calendar>
```

and in my component:

```
enddate: Date;
```

When sending this value via REST, I have the following code (including check):

```
createPSP(project_num: string, financialItem: FinancialItem) {
    this.logger.info("Startdate is " + financialItem.startDate);
    this.logger.info("Enddate is " + financialItem.endDate);
    let order_num = financialItem.orderNumber;
    let psp_num = financialItem.pspNumber;
    return this.http.post(`${httpBaseUrl}/project/${project_num}/order/${order_num}/addFinancialItem/${psp_num}`, financialItem).pipe();
  }
```

Output (which is right):

[image]

Then I save it in my backend in a `LocalDate`-variable (which converts to `date`-type in MySQL). Now what happens is that I insert `31.12.2018` and I get (in my Converter in backend) `30.12.2018` and in MySQL `29.12.2018`. Why is that the case?

Edit: When I change `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` I am just getting `30.12.2018` in MySQL instead of `29.12.2018` which is obviously still wrong.

**Some more code:**

I defined my MySQL-Column like this (in my Entity):

```
@Entity
class FinancialItemDto {
    //...
    @Column(name = "ENDDATE", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

**In the Controller:**

```
 public ResponseEntity addFinancialItem(@PathVariable String project_num, @PathVariable String order_num,
            @PathVariable String psp_num, @RequestBody FinancialItemDto financialItemDto) {
        try {
            this.financialItemService.saveItemGivenProjectAndOrderNumber(financialItemDto, order_num);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException e) {
            this.logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(e.getUserMessage());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**In the Service:**

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveItemGivenProjectAndOrderNumber(FinancialItemDto financialItemDto, String orderNumber)
            throws NoSuchEntityException {
        OrderEntity order = this.orderRepository.findByOrderNumber(orderNumber).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NoSuchEntityException("Order with number " + orderNumber + " could not be found.",
                        "Der Abruf wurde nicht gefunden."));
        OrdertypesEntity ordertype = this.ordertypesRepository.findByShorthand(financialItemDto.getOrderType())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchEntityException("Ordertype " + financialItemDto.getOrderType()
                        + " for creating FI to order " + orderNumber + " could not be found.",
                        "Der Abruftyp wurde nicht gefunden."));
        FinancialItemEntity financialItemEntity = FinancialItemConverter.dtoToEntity(financialItemDto, ordertype,
                order);
        this.entityManager.persist(financialItemEntity);
    }
```

**The Dto on TS-Side defines the date like follows:**

```
 export class FinancialItem {
   endDate: Date;
   //...
 }
```

**My Converter just passes on:**

```
  public static FinancialItemEntity dtoToEntity(FinancialItemDto financialItemDto, OrdertypesEntity ordertype, OrderEntity order) {
        FinancialItemEntity financialItemEntity = new FinancialItemEntity( (...), financialItemDto.getEndDate(), (...));
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(FinancialItemConverter.class).info("Got Date Value: " + financialItemDto.getEndDate());  //gives: Got Date Value: 2018-12-30 instead of value 31.12.2018
        return financialItemEntity;
    }
```

**Update:**

A workaround for the REST-Service to "loose" one day was saving the date in long-format and then pass this and convert it back. Sadly, when calling `repository.save()`-function, the logger calls that when I inserted `2018-12-01` the date-value is also `2018-12-01`, but MySQL says it is `2018-11-30` in my database. I cannot make out what is happening there:

```
this.logger.info("Startdate is " + financialItemDto.getStartDate()); //2018-12-01
this.logger.info("Startdate is " + financialItemEntity.getStartDate()); //2018-12-01
this.financialItemRepository.save(financialItemEntity);     
this.logger.info("Startdate (received) is " + this.financialItemRepository.getFinancialItemByPSPNumber(financialItemDto.getPspNumber()).get().getStartDate()); //2018-12-01
```

Comment: Have you checked the time zone that you are sending to the server? Check the time zone of your server too.

Comment: Can show you the output in the console log before you send the date to your converter? Also, can you show the code on the backend that converts and finally submits through JPA? You may redact anything which is sensitive.

Comment: @L.Figueredo For the moment I am just working on localhost

Comment: @Nikhil I tried to add some more code, but basically this is just passing on of the value, no "real" logic behind it. The convertions could be from `enddate: Date` (TS) to `LocalDate` (Java) and `LocalDate` (Entity) to `date`(MySQL) where these could happen, but still I have no idea why, everything is running just locally in the same jar on the same device.

Comment: You are printing start date value: `LoggerFactory.getLogger(FinancialItemConverter.class).info("Got Date Value: " + financialItemDto.getStartDate());` I thought you had issue with end date.

Comment: @Nikhil Got it with both dates, just had endDate represented here in this question (since the solution should work accordingly for the other). The result is for both dates the same (the day difference), I copied the wrong line there. I updated it :)

Comment: Ok :). What do see when you do this `{{enddate}}` in Angular? You can add it after the `<p-calendar>` tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185792/discussion-between-nikhil-and-rudiger).